# Can I control the order in which javascript / jQuery events fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

**Background**

I've got asp.net webform with a grid, and when users update textboxes in that grid, the onchange event kicks off a WebMethod call and updates the rest of the changed row. Nothing is saved at that time -- we're just updating the UI.

To commit the changes, you click the save button.

This actually works reliably in almost every scenario. However, there is one very persistant one that it feels like I should be able to solve, but it's time to call in the specialists.

**The Problem Scenario**

I'm using jQuery to capture the enter key, and unfortunately that event fires first, causing the page to submit before the callback completes. The row is not updated correctly. Stale and bewildering data is saved.

**Update**

I don't think you can make the enter behavior depend on the callback, because you could save without changing a row. In that case, if you didn't change a row, it would never save.

Now if there was some way to inspect javascript's internal list of things to do, or maybe create my own and then manage it somehow, that would work. But that's some heavy lifting for something that should be easy. So unless an expert tells me otheriwse, I have to assume that's wrong.

**Attempts**

Right now I'm using the built-in jQuery events and I've got this elaborate setTimeout persisting the fact that a save was attempted, pausing long enough for the WebMethod to at least get called, and relying on the callback to do the submit. But it turns out javascript ansychrony doesn't work the way I hoped, and the onchange event doesn't even fire until that chunk of code completes. That was surprising.

I was thinking I could use my own little object to queue up these events in the right order and find a clever way to trigger that, etc.

This all seems like the wrong direction. Surely this is insane overkill, this is a common problem and I'm overlooking a simple solution because I don't work in javascript 24/7.

Right?

**Code**

Here's what I've got right this minute. This obviously doesn't work -- I was trying to take advantage of the async nature of jquery, but all of this apparently has to conclude before the row's onchange event event fires:

```
$(document).bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        handleEnter();
        return false; //apparently I should be using e.preventDefault() here. 
    }
});


function handleEnter() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (recalculatingRow) { //recalculatingRow is a bit managed by the onchange code.
            alert('recalculating...');
            return true; //recur
        }

        //$('input[id$="ButtonSave"]').click();
        alert('no longer recalculating. click!');
        return false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

And then a typical row looks like this. Note that I'm not using jquery to bind this:

```
 <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridOrderItems$ctl02$TextOrderItemDose" type="text" value="200.00" maxlength="7" id="ctl00_MainContent_GridOrderItems_ctl02_TextOrderItemDose" onchange="recalculateOrderItemRow(this);" style="width:50px;" />
```

I could post the code for recalculateOrderItemRow, but it's really long and right now the problem is that it doens't fire until the after keypress event concludes.

**Update Dos**
According to [Nick Fitzgerald](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/35/) (and man is that a cool article) the use of setTimeout should cause this to become async. Digging further into interactions between setTimeout and jQuery, as well as interactions between normal javascript events and jQuery events.

Comment: Can you set a flag? Something like var flag = false. When the onchange event fires, set flag = false. When the callback fires, set flag = true. Then use a jquery .submit event and check if( flag !== true ){  e.preventDefault();}. Hopefully that makes sense. Any chance you could post your js that handles the form?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte that's actually exactly what I've been working on. But the flag never gets set, because the onchange event (which is plain old javascript) doesn't fire at all until the keypress event finishes. I will post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hideous mass of workarounds below, which effectively took me all day today and half of yesterday to write, seems to solve every permutation.

The amusing thing is that enter itself doesn't trigger onchange, if you call e.preventDefault(). Why would it? The change doesn't actually happen until the default behavior of clicking the save button occurs.

Very little else about this is amusing.

```
//Used in handleEnter and GridOrderItems.js to handle a deferred an attempt to save by hitting enter (see handleEnter).
var isSaving = false; 
var saveOnID = '';

//When one of the fields that trigger WebMethods get focus, we put the value in here
//so we can determine whether the field is dirty in handleEnter.
var originalVal = 0;

//These fields trigger callbacks. On focus, we need to save their state so we can
//determine if they're dirty in handleEnter().
$('[id$=TextOrderItemDose], [id$=TextOrderItemUnits]').live("focus", function() {
    originalVal = this.value;
});

$(document).bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { //enter pressed.
        e.preventDefault();
        handleEnter();
    }
});

//Problem:
//In the products grid, TextOrderItemDose and TextOrderItemUnits both have js in their onchange events
//that trigger webmethod calls and use the results to update the row. Prsssing enter is supposed to 
//save the form, but if you do it right after changing one of those text fields, the row doesn't always
//get updated due to the async nature of js's events. That leads to stale data being saved.  
//Solution:
//First we capture Enter and prevent its default behaviors. From there, we check to see if one of our
//special boxes has focus. If so, we do some contortions to figure out if it's dirty, and use isSaving
//and saveOnID to defer the save operation until the callback returns. 
//Otherwise, we save as normal.
function handleEnter() {
    var focusedElement = $("[id$=TextOrderItemDose]:focus, [id$=TextOrderItemUnits]:focus")

    //did we press enter with a field that triggers a callback selected?
    if (isCallbackElement(focusedElement) && isElementDirty(focusedElement)) { 
        //Set details so that the callback can know that we're saving.
        isSaving = true;
        saveOnID = focusedElement.attr('id');

        //Trigger blur to cause the callback, if there was a change. Then bring the focus right back.
        focusedElement.trigger("change");
        focusedElement.focus();
    } else {
        forceSave();
    }
}

function isCallbackElement(element) {
    return (element.length == 1);
}

function isElementDirty(element) {
    if (element.length != 1) 
        return false;

    return (element.val() != originalVal);
}

function forceSave() {
    isSaving = false;
    saveOnID = '';

    $('input[id$="ButtonSave"]').click();
}
```

This gets called in the change event for the textboxes:

```
function recalculateOrderItemRow(textbox) {
    //I'm hiding a lot of code that gathers and validates form data. There is a ton and it's not interesting.

    //Call the WebMethod on the server to calculate the row. This will trigger a callback when complete.
    PageMethods.RecalculateOrderItemRow($(textbox).attr('id'),
                                   orderItemDose,
                                   ProductItemSize,
                                   orderItemUnits,
                                   orderItemUnitPrice,
                                   onRecalculateOrderItemRowComplete);

}
```

And then, at the end of the  WebMethod callback code we pull the updated form values out, put the caret where it needs to be using jquery.caret, and check to see if we need to force a save:

```
function onRecalculateOrderItemRowComplete(result) {
    var sender, row;

    sender = $('input[id="' + result.Sender + '"]');
    row = $(sender).closest('tr');

    row.find('input[id$="TextOrderItemDose"]').val(result.Dose);
    row.find('input[id$="TextOrderItemUnits"]').val(result.Units);
    row.find('span[id$="SpanTotalPrice"]').html(formatCurrency(result.TotalPrice));

    calculateGrandTotalPrice();
    $(document.activeElement).select();

    if (isSaving && saveOnID == result.Sender) {
        forceSave();
    }
}
```

result.Sender is the ID of the calling control, which I stuffed into the WebMethod call and then returned. saveOnID may not be perfect, and it might actually be even better to maintain a counter of active/uncallback-ed WebMethod calls to be totally sure that everything wraps up before save. Whew.

Comment: Not bad! Assuming you are focusing/blurring to force `change`, you could try `focusedElement.trigger('change')` instead.

Comment: @bfavaretto I incorporated that suggestion, and added some more goo to handle the case of the field not being dirty. Whew. I like javascript and jquery, but seriously, things like this are still way too arcane.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> shouldn't be causing you so much trouble! Make sure you have something like this on your code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like you *do* want to save on <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but only after the UI is updated on `change`. That is possible. You could use a flag a Matthew Blancarte suggested above, trigger save from the `change` callback, and get rid of the `setTimeout`.

But I wouldn't recommend that. **You are better off relying solely on the save button for saving**. If you don't, your users will have to wait for two async operations to complete before saving is finished. So you'd have to block the UI, or keep track of all async operations, aborting some as needed. I think it's not worthy, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> becomes less intuitive for the users if saving takes too long.

Comment: Couldn't resist the `<kbd>` :)

Comment: Hrmm, okay, so here's the only thing -- what if they hit enter to save, but no row was changed? There are other fields that can be updated that are not grid-related. It's almost like I need to push this event back (.bindLast? But I don't think that will work with this syntax) or manually re-order the events somehow.

Comment: Well, in this case I think you'd have to prevent the default on enter, manually check if anything changed, and then submit if nothing changed. As for reordering the events, I believe that's only possible for multiple handlers to the same event (like multiple click handlers on the same element), but not between events. The `keydown` event will always fire before `change`, I don't think you can change that.

Comment: Ouch. Hey, isn't it true that if I put the keydown code in a setTimeout, other events should be able to fire async while the timer ticks down?

Comment: Yes, but there's no guarantee that the async operations will be finished by the time the `setTimeout` callback runs! And if you don't prevent the default on keydown, the form will submit anyway...

Comment: All i need to do is guarantee that the onchange event has time to start -- then I can get clever with a counter or a bit to change the way submit works. Right now it isn't firing -- it seems that my code is blocking and not running async the way everything I'm reading says it should. Digging deeper into that now...

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your javascript?  Sounds like you're on the right track.  I would change my OnChange events to increment a variable before making the AJAX call.  I'll call the variable inProcess and initialize it to zero.  When the AJAX call comes back, I would update the inProcess to the current value minus one.  On the Enter key event, I would check to that inProcess equals zero.  If not, you could either warn the user or set a timeout to try again in a bit.

Comment: that sounds interesting, and more foolproof than a bit. The biggest problem remains that the enter key event always seems to happen *before* the onchange event fires - and in my tests, the onchange event doesn't even start until the keypress event completely concludes. Is that because I'm not using jquery to bind my onchange event? If so can you tell me why? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could unbind the Enter key capture while you are in the onChange event, then rebind it at the end of the callback function. If you post some code, I could give a more specific answer.

Comment: That sounds awesome. What if they hit enter to save and there is no callback because they didn't change a row? (for instance, change a row, hit tab to update the row, then hit enter). Is there a way to push the event to the end of the queue somehow, so that it fires last in all scenarios?

Comment: Well, the system is not in a state where the Enter key should be accepted (similar to the old problem of users double-clicking the Submit button). Maybe a better idea is to disable the Enter key until you are ready. Users will likely just hit Enter again if they see it didn't work the first time.

Comment: No, it's perfectly valid to hit save without changing a row -- they could change the field, hit tab, then hit enter. Or they could change something that isn't in the grid and hit enter. I've got workaround that feels close to clicking, stay tuned if you're interested.

Comment: "...causing the page to submit before the callback completes." If the system was in a state ready for the user to hit Enter, I don't think you would have asked your question!

Comment: Hah. I see what you mean. I can't just hack it so that the button is disabled here, this is a requirement. But good thinking outside the box.

Comment: I'll look at the code some more and see if there is something more suitable as a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you shouldn't be calling the WebMethod asynchronously. Call it synchronously, and on success, save your data.

Comment: But what if you hit save without changing a row? :) The save still needs to happen.

Comment: Ok - so call the save method when save is clicked?

Comment: I wish it was that easy. Check out the answer I posted if you're interested.

Comment: Can you post more if the code -- like where/how you are calling the WebMethod

Comment: I did this with some rather complicated JS workflows on my site but the browser (chrome) complains about synchronous ajax as "Deprecated". I wasn't willing to take the risk that it would one day actually be forced to async despite my setting and break everything. The rule for todays ajax is "Do not use Synchronous ajax"